# Problem with drawing ccDrawCircle / ccDrawPoly

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to show bounding rectangles around my sprites to refine the collision detection and handling.

I have used following code to display circle or polygon

```
        glColor4ub(255, 255, 0, 255);
    glLineWidth(2);
    CGPoint vertices2[] = { ccp(30,130), ccp(30,230), ccp(50,200) };
    ccDrawPoly( vertices2, 3, YES);

    ccDrawCircle(ccp(0,0), 50, 360, 5, NO);
```

as mentioned in drawPrimitivesTest.m file in cocos2d.

i removed all background sprites also. but it is not showing me any circle or polygon.

can anybody has faced same problem? how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not put that code outside of the draw method**

**TIP:**
Every CocosNode has a "draw" method.
In the "draw" method you put all the code that actually draws your node.
 And Test1 is a subclass of TestDemo, which is a subclass of Layer, which is a subclass of CocosNode.
 As you can see the drawing primitives aren't CocosNode objects. They are just helper
         functions that let's you draw basic things like: points, line, polygons and circles.

**Answering**

TIP:
         Don't draw your stuff outide the "draw" method. Otherwise it wont get transformed.

TIP: If you want to rotate/translate/scale a circle or any other "primtive", you can do it by rotating
         the node. eg:
            `self.rotation = 90`;

Comment: welcome ....For more help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Comment: Is this still true in 3.0?